# Using a static UITableViewController to create two sections with the first section having a non-static number of cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` that I'm building up in my application. This `UITableViewController` (`SelectedLanguages`) is called from another `UITableViewController` (`ChooseLanguage`) where there is a static list of languages for the user to select.

In the `SelectedLanguages` `UITableViewController`, I want to achieve the following:

- 2 Sections
- The first section will have between 1 and 5 cells
- The second section will always have 12 cells.

The number of cells in the first section is entirely dependent on which language the user chooses in the `ChooseLanguage` `UITableViewController`. For example, clicking on English will mean the first section in the `SelectedLanguage` `UITableViewController` will have 5 cells, but choosing `French` in the `ChooseLanguage` `UITableViewController` will mean the first section in the `SelectedLanguage` will only have 1 cell.

As mentioned, the second section will always have 12 cells in the `SelectedLanguage`.

I have designed this `UITableViewController` in `Interface Builder`. What I've seen is that only if the the Content is specified as `Static Cells` can you have multiple "sections".

Even if you set the Content to Dynamic and Grouped, I can't seem to find a way to determine sections other than in code.

The reason I'm defining this in `Interface Builder` is because section 1 and section 2 will need to have a very customised layout of the size of the cells, as well as the labels that go into each cell.

The content of the first section is not dynamic; it is static because while building this application, I'll know exactly how many cells there should be in the first section for each language, so in my head, it is correct to use a Static cell.

**My question is, how can I achieve setting the number of cells in the top section, in code?**

In the prepareForSegue of the ChooseLanguage, I could check the called cell title and then perform some action in the SelectedTransactions. The action to perform here is what I'm confused about.

I know there's the method `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` in the `UITableView` `Data Source`, but I'm not sure how and what to do with this with my particular situation.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My easiest answer for your question is below

in .m
         import "ViewController.h"

```
     @interface ViewController () 
     {
       NSMutableArray *arraysection1;
       NSMutableArray *arraysection2;

     }
     @end

     @implementation ViewController

     - (void)viewDidLoad 
     {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        arraySection1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",nil];
        arraySection2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",nil];
     }

  #UITableView Delegate Methods

     #UITableView DataSource Methods
     - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     {
        //If you have 2 sections,
        return 2;
     }
     -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {
        //set row of two sections with condition
        if(section==0)
        {
           return arraySection1.count;
        }
        else
        {
           return arraySection2.count;
        }

     }
     -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
        static NSString *strCellIdentifier = @"CellIndentifier";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCellIdentifier];
       }

       if(indexPath.section==0)
       {
          cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arraySection1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
          NSLog(@"The textLabel is-%@",cell.textLabel.text);
       }
       else
       {
         cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arraySection2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
         NSLog(@"The textLabel is-%@",cell.textLabel.text);
       }
       return cell;
     }

    #UITableView Delegate Methods
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
       if(indexPath.section==0)
       {
          if(indexPath.row==0)
          {
            //Do whatever you want here
          }
          else if(indexPath.row==1)
          {
            //Do whatever you want here
          }
          else if(indexPath.row==2)
          {
            //Do whatever you want here
          }
          else if(indexPath.row==3)
          {
            //Do whatever you want here
          }
          else 
          {
            //Do whatever you want here
          }

       }
       else
       {
          if(indexPath.row==0)
          {
            //Do whatever you want here
          }
          else if(indexPath.row==1)
          {
            //Do whatever you want here
          }
          else if(indexPath.row==2)
          {
            //Do whatever you want here
          }
          else if(indexPath.row==3)
          {
            //Do whatever you want here
          }
          else 
          {
            //Do whatever you want here
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Could I still use IB to create custom sub-labels, etc (which don't have to be updated in code) and use your code in the same way?

Comment: Yeah use my code that what i posted.Because i wrote the static cell according to your question.

Comment: Definitely you can get solution.

Comment: If my code is helpful for you,please tick and give me the mark because it is very useful for others if they see your question.

Comment: Thanks very much - this makes sense and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are describing it sounds like your tableView should be dynamic.

You will have to handle this programmatically, forget about interface builder

Here is what you need:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;//2 Sections
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            //The first section will have between 1 and 5 cells
            //Put the logic to return the correct number of cells
            return 5;
            break;
        case 1:
            //The second section will always have 12 cells.
            return 12;
            break;                
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            [[cell textLabel] setText:@"same title section 1"];
            break;
        case 1:
            [[cell textLabel] setText:@"same title section 2"];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @meda - that's extremely helpful. I'm quite a newbie to programming and I don't want to mess around too much with code, for something that I could possibly do in Interface Builder. The 12 cells in the second section will always have the same titles and the first section will contain always the same titles for all 5; it's just a case of how many do I display. So in the code that you have there, in the rows and where you said to put the logic, could I put the correct number of cells based on the cell that I clicked on in the previous UITableView?

Comment: Interface is not that flexible you know, I updated my code to show you how to put the titles. as for the logic it could be based on condition or perhaps your datasource array count.

Comment: Thanks so much and absolutely, I shall indeed work towards understanding doing this in code. I appreciate your answer.